# Weird javascript behaviour, works on one page but not another

Tags: javascript

I have a simple bit of code that was taken from an answer to another question on here, that works perfectly in the first page - an html form - that I have used it on. The code is to count and suitably colourise count report text in relation to textbox input fields. Here is a sample of the page html:

```
<..snip..>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><span class="h3">5.2</span>Please detail the travel and associated accomodation costs required for the international speaker(s) to attend the conference.<br>
   <textarea id="input_5_2" name="input_5_2" class="large" placeholder="Please detail the travel and associated accomodation costs required for the international speaker(s) to attend the conference" maxlength="1000" required><?=$input_5_2?></textarea><br>
   <span id="count_5_2" class="count"></span>
   <span id="errorText_5_2" class="errorOutput"></span></td>
   <td class="top"><br><span id="resultImg_5_2"></span></td>
  </tr>
<..snip..>
```

And so the relevant JS for this specific section. This resides within a file that loads within the head:

```
// Character counting and warning JS functions
$(window).load(function() {
    var countChars = function(input, counter, maxCount) {
        var diff = (maxCount - $(input).val().length), color = 'ff0000';
        if (diff > maxCount * 0.20) {  /* 500/2500 */
            color = '55a500';
        } else if (diff > maxCount * 0.04) { /* 100/2500 */
            color = 'ff6600';
        }
        $(counter).html('<span style="color: #' + color + ';">Characters remaining: ' + diff + '</span>');
    };

    countChars('#input_5_2','#count_5_2', 1000);
    $("#input_5_2").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_5_2', 1000) } );

});
```

I have cut the other text input field references form the code as they are ot really important to demonstrate what is going on. This works perfectly fine. On this page. But when I use the exact same bit of JS code for another page with a different form, it fails to work.

Not working version looks like this (full code supplied this time):

```
// Character counting and warning JS functions
$(window).load(function() {
    var countChars = function(input, counter, maxCount) {
        var diff = (maxCount - $(input).val().length), color = 'ff0000';
        if (diff > maxCount * 0.20) {  /* 500/2500 */
            color = '55a500';
        } else if (diff > maxCount * 0.04) { /* 100/2500 */
            color = 'ff6600';
        }
        $(counter).html('<span style="color: #' + color + ';">Characters remaining: ' + diff + '</span>');
    };

    countChars('#input_themeAndPurpose','#count_themeAndPurpose', 2500);
    $("#input_themeAndPurpose").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_themeAndPurpose', 2500) } );

    countChars('#input_activsAndOutcomes','#count_activsAndOutcomes', 2500);
    $("#input_activsAndOutcomes").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_activsAndOutcomes', 2500) } );

    countChars('#input_benefitToPriSec','#count_benefitToPriSec', 2500);
    $("#input_benefitToPriSec").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_benefitToPriSec', 2500) } );

    countChars('#input_fitAGsStraObj','#count_fitAGsStraObj', 2500);
    $("#input_fitAGsStraObj").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_fitAGsStraObj', 2500) } );

    countChars('#input_support','#count_support', 2500);
    $("#input_support").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_support', 2500) } );

    countChars('#input_dessemination','#count_dessemination', 2500);
    $("#input_dessemination").keyup(function() { countChars(this, '#count_dessemination', 2500) } );

});
```

I get no error message that I can understand to distinguish a difference in these two peices of code. The only error I get is:

```
Timestamp: 2/03/2015 9:28:31 a.m.
Error: TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined
Source File: http://callisto/www/domain/js/app_VisFelAp.js
Line: 782
```

Which when looked at, shows up as being this particular line in the above code:

```
var diff = (maxCount - $(input).val().length), color = 'ff0000';
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am missing as to why the exact same code works fine in one page and fails in another?

Comment: `input` is one of the parameters of `countChars`. Maybe in one of the calls to your function you used an id that doesn't exist. I suggest you comment out all of those function calls and call only one at a time to find out which call generates the error.

Comment: The error does not appear to be attached to an input, but rather an issue with the var. I have removed the entire block of code and inserted the code from the other form that works fine and I get the exact same error, in the same place. So perhaps it is caused by something elsewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, it was an error in the naming structure. Ignore/Delete question. Thanks